# Deleting a heap variable giving munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error

Tags: c, pointers

I've created a heap variable and allocated a stack variable address. And deleting the heap variable after use. All this in one function.
I'm unable to understand why I get munmap_chuck(): invalid pointer error, though I feel I didn't do anything out of scope.

Doing this

```
void heapExample(void)
{
    int * intPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int val = 92;
    intPtr = &val;
    printf("Value: %d\n", *intPtr);
    free(intPtr);
}

int main()
{
    heapExample();
    return 0;
}
```

is giving this error

```
Value: 92
*** Error in `./main': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xbfbce8e8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x67d2a)[0xb7646d2a]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6e9c7)[0xb764d9c7]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6f051)[0xb764e051]
./main[0x804857a]
./main[0x80484b1]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf6)[0xb75f7196]
./main[0x80483c1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6947062    /home/rahul/Documents/c_prac/main
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 6947062    /home/rahul/Documents/c_prac/main
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 6947062    /home/rahul/Documents/c_prac/main
08814000-08835000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b75df000-b7791000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2495288    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
b7791000-b7792000 ---p 001b2000 08:01 2495288    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
b7792000-b7794000 r--p 001b2000 08:01 2495288    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
b7794000-b7795000 rw-p 001b4000 08:01 2495288    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
b7795000-b7798000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77a2000-b77be000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2491581    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b77be000-b77bf000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 2491581    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b77bf000-b77c0000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 2491581    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b77c0000-b77c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77c3000-b77c5000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b77c5000-b77c6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77c6000-b77e8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2495287    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
b77e8000-b77e9000 r--p 00021000 08:01 2495287    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
b77e9000-b77ea000 rw-p 00022000 08:01 2495287    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
bfbb0000-bfbd1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Because you have destroyed the pointer value returned by malloc, by overwriting it with `&val`. Did you mean `*intPtr = val`?

Comment: Yes!
I understood my mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass to `free()` pointers returned by `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`, `intPtr` is not such a pointer because

```
intPtr = &val;
```

assigns the address of `val` to the pointer.

Pointers are that, pointers. You `malloc()` to point to valid memory. You make pointers to adresses of variables in your program or to memory from the heap that will be returned by any of these `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`.

When you request memory from the heap, you MUST release that memory with a call to `free()`. But you can have pointers pointing to stack variables which have automatic storage duration. When you define a variable in a block of code, it has a scope that is the actual block where it was defined. You can make a poitner to it, but it will be deallocated without your intervention, it will be automatically deallocated when it goes out of scope.

Having a pointer to such a variable means that you have to be careful, not to attempt `free()`ing it and not to access it after the variable whose address your pointer has stored goes out of scope.

Comment: From Weather Vane's comment & your answer, I understood that my intention was to do *intPtr = val; My mistake was that I assigned the address of val to intPtr. Thanks you :)